# AES128 Decryption in IOS Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, aes, swift4

I've been trying to decode a **AES 128-Bit encrypted text** using the password given using `Swift`. I tried many libraries like `AES128` and some other too.. But in everything, it's only possible to decrypt the text which is encrypted using the same code. But here I have a text and password which I need to decrypt. The cypher text is **AES 128-bit**. Can anyone specify me any library or **method to decrypt my AES 128-bit Cypher text in Swift**.

Thanks in advance :)

In the code below, I got a Thread ; *Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

As you can see, I have an already encrypted text and a password, I want to get the actual decrypted text from them...

I've added two files WebCrypto.swift and WebCrypto.js as they specified in the ReadMe file of WebCrypto library

```
let crypto = WebCrypto()

let password = "Q@*Amn!"

let encrypted = "NilZ9gpu1M3KUnEyN9scllyV3aN7NSSPJXwbOy7qTOk="

let enData = encrypted.data(using: .utf8)

self.crypto.decrypt(data: enData!, password: password, callback{(decrypted: Data?, error: Error?) in

print(String(data: decrypted!, encoding: .utf8)!)

})
```

Comment: Post some code, it'll help us out a bit

Comment: @jacks205 I don't have any specific code to be attached. Actually I was asking for a library or pod to be used for decrypting 128bit AES cypher in swift...  :(

Comment: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

Comment: *"I tried with AES128 library and return 'nil' after decryption"* – Which library, which code? We cannot *guess* what the problem is.

Comment: Check AES, https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption/tree/master/iOS

Comment: @MartinR . AES128 is a library available in cocoapods.  check https://cocoapods.org/?q=aes128

Comment: @aBilal17 Cross-Platform-AES didn't work actually.. I tried.. I am not able to add those Objective-C to swift file..

Comment: @PPL I also believe CryptoSwift may help. But I tried it many times.. Not able to get the idea.. can u please figure it out how to use AES 128-bit explained in that ? I just have a encrypted string and a password for it...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do AES `encryption` and `decryption` using [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) this way,

```
do {
    let tmpString = "This is test string."
    let aes = try AES(key: "password12345678", iv: "drowssapdrowssap") // aes128
    let ciphertext = try aes.encrypt(Array(tmpString.utf8))

    let decryptedText = try aes.decrypt(ciphertext)
    let data = Data(bytes: decryptedText, count: decryptedText.count)

    if let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(string)
    } else {
        print("not a valid UTF-8 sequence")
    }
} catch { }
```

Here `print(string)` will be `This is test string.`

**UPDATE**

You can do it using this [library](https://github.com/etienne-martin/WebCrypto.swift)

```
let crypto = WebCrypto()

let input = Data("This is a string".utf8)
let password = "password123"

crypto.encrypt(data: input, password: password, callback: {(encrypted: Data?, error: Error?) in
    print(encrypted!) //encrypted data

    crypto.decrypt(data: encrypted!, password: password, callback: {(decrypted: Data?, error: Error?) in
        print(String(data: decrypted!, encoding: .utf8)!)
    })
})
```

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: I don't have an iv ...what is 'iv' ? I just have a key like _"E6M*@_LIMITedIBB"_

Comment: I accept that this code is working as it is (I tried it already).. but see there is nothing like 'iv' which I can specify. I just uploaded a screenshot of a sample in the question, please see it. In that I gave the cyphertext and a password, and below you can see the decrypted output. The same I needed, in which I don't need to specify any 'iv'.. @PPL, you are helping really, but I am not finding a solution exactly.  :(

Comment: @Ashique giving you a solution, please wait

Comment: Iam working on it.. Once It is done, I'll accept the answer and let you know... :) By the way, thanks a lot...let me try it ...

Comment: I tried that code.. can you please see the screenshot of thread in the question, which I just now added!

Comment: @Ashique Please post code, not screenshot, how can I copy string

Comment: @Ashique you should update question instead of posting answer

Comment: Iam sorry about that.. Iam a new user to stackoverflow.. I'll keep that in mind next time...

Comment: From where you are getting encrypted string?

Comment: For testing purpose I created encrypted string using [https://aesencryption.net/] ..

Comment: Actually, you didn't get my point..Consider I have a Encrypted text which my friend gave me along with a password. When I used it in [https://aesencryption.net/] I got the decrypted text. So I need to do the same in swift. I just need to use that pre-encrypted text for decryption only..  Hope you understand it... :)